# Erro Uncaught (in promise) Error: Element is not attached to a Document ao tentar gerar um PDF de uma página HTML

Tags: javascript, jspdf, html2canvas

Estou tentando gerar um PDF de uma página feita em HTML. Essa página possui um gráfico criado com Chart Js. Eu gostaria de ao clicar no botão, fosse gerado um PDF do gráfico. Porém, ao clicar no Botão, é gerado o erro Uncaught (in promise) Error: Element is not attached to a Document. Vocês sabem onde posso estar cometendo alguma falha para apresentação de tal erro ?

- Estou usando **html2canvas** (pois andei lendo que é necessário primeiro converter o arquivo para PNG).
- Estou usando também o **jspdf** para converter o arquivo para PDF.
- **Segue abaixo o código** que está apresentando problemas:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  //Chamando função ao carregar a página.
  let pegar = pegarStatusAtividades(configuraDados);

  html2canvas(document.querySelector("#canvas_status_atividades")).then(canvas => {
    document.body.appendChild(canvas)
  });

  // Função que transforma canvas em imagem e exporta para PDF
  // Você pode usar $(.'elemento').click() do jQuery para disparar a função 
  $('#gerar-pdf').on('click', function() {
    html2canvas($('#canvas_status_atividades'), {
      onrendered: function(canvas) {
        var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'mm');
        pdf.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 10, 10);
        pdf.save('test.pdf');
      }
    });
  });

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <title>Aprendendo</title>


  <link href="_bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- ARQUIVO CSS DO BOOTSTRAP -->

  <link href="_chart/dist/Chart.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="_chart/dist/Chart.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <h1 class="text-center">Gráficos de Status das Atividades</h1>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container-fluid" id="container-canvas">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-8 offset-lg-2">
        <canvas id="canvas_status_atividades" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-8 offset-lg-2">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="gerar-pdf">Gerar PDF</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <script src="_jquery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <!-- ARQUIVO JQUERY -->
  <script src="_bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!-- ARQUIVO BOOTSTRAP -->
  <script src="_jsPDF/dist/jspdf.min.js"></script>
  <!-- ARQUIVO jspdf -->
  <script src="_html2canvas/html2canvas.js"></script>
  <!-- ARQUIVO html2canvas -->
  <script src="scripts/script.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

**OBS**: O Gráfico é gerado sem problemas com o Chart JS:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu não entendo, você não é o primeiro que vejo fazendo isto, eu fui um colaborador do projeto html2canvas (foi só umas 2 modificações de código) e não entendo porque as pessoas insistem em usar html2canvas para obter a imagem de um canvas real.

Se o elemento **já é canvas**:

```
<canvas id="canvas_status_atividades" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Basta usar `.toDataURL()` para obter a imagem, exemplo:

```
$('#gerar-pdf').on('click', function() {
    var canvas_status_atividades = document.getElementById('canvas_status_atividades');
    var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'mm');
    pdf.addImage(canvas_status_atividades.toDataURL(), 'PNG', 10, 10);
    pdf.save('test.pdf');
});
```

---

Já o erro `Element is not attached to a Document` pode ser bug da versão do HTML2CANVAS que está usando, não sei qual está usando, mas talvez você esteja desatualizado, ou pode ser algum script seu que está "desanexando" o elemento do corpo do DOM, mas não é algo relacionado ao seu código.

Comment: Muito bom, Guilherme. Muito obrigado mesmo, cara. Deixa eu te fazer mais uma pergunta. Se eu quiser, ao invés de pegar só um gráfico, pegar a página toda (Pois a página tem vários gráficos), como eu faria ?

Comment: Tipo, pegar tudo mesmo. Menu, rodapé e outros elementos html da página.

Comment: @Jason-TheInternship. neste caso vai ter que usar o html2canvas mesmo, mas dá uma olhada se está usando a versão mais recente e se não tem outro script atrapalhando, eu pessoalmente em seu lugar trocaria o canvas na hora no snapshot pela imagem feita pelo toDataURL e em seguida usaria o HTML2CANVAS

Comment: Estou usando a mais recente sim. Peguei no site https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/.

Comment: Guilherme, teria como você me ajudar quanto a isso ? Eu sou leigo e é a primeira vez que estou usando o html2canvas e o jspdf.

Comment: @Jason-TheInternship.pode ser algum script seu que esteja afetando o canvas, tentou usar `html2canvas(document.body, {` e ocorre o mesmo erro?

Comment: Quando faço isso, não é gerado erro, mas também o PDF não é gerado.

Comment: @Jason-TheInternship. mas se nada é gerado é pq tem outro erro, vc fez a minha sugestão, somente no momento do snapshot trocar o canvas pela imagem gerada e depois aplicar o html2canvas?

Comment: O snapshot ocorre no momento da linha do pdf.addImage ?

Comment: @Jason-TheInternship. pega `canvas_status_atividades.toDataURL()` adiciona com `var nova = new Image; nova.src = canvas_status_atividades.toDataURL();`, ai pega a variavel `nova`, ficando assim: `canvas_status_atividades.parentNode.replaceChild(canvas_status_atividades, nova);`, ai dentro do `onrendered` faça ao contrário para restaurar: `onrendered: function () { nova.parentNode.replaceChild(nova, canvas_status_atividades); ... }` e tenta ao menos pegar o screenshot e abrir em um `window.open`, a parte do PDF vc faz depois.

Comment: Foi mal, Guilherme. Eu não consegui acompanhar seu raciocínio. Eu vou dar uma caçada no google. Mas agradeço a sua resposta para minha pergunta. Já me foi útil na questão de imprimir os gráficos. Obrigado!

Comment: Guilherme, ai o script ficaria mais ou menos assim no início ? https://jsfiddle.net/28pycq4x/

Comment: @Jason-TheInternship. você colou o onrendered solto, faz assim: https://pastebin.com/raw/U0zSbAKR

Comment: Guilherme, deu uma erro na linha do replaceChild. Mostrou que um parametro do replace não é filho do outro. Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'replaceChild' on 'Node': The node to be replaced is not a child of this node.

Comment: E mesmo nesse caso, isso não faria a mesma coisa que aquele código, que mostra só os PDF, fazia ?

Comment: Eu vou deixar o meu código completo para vc ver como está. Se você puder me ajudar a resolver isso, eu ficaria grato. Estava tentando gerar esses PDF em PHP com o Wkhtmltopdf, mas também encontrei problemas. Os gráficos do Charts não aparecem com essa lib. Estou a 4 dias tentando fazer isso, mas não venho obtendo sucesso. Segue o link. https://jsfiddle.net/97ub84aL/

Comment: @Jason-TheInternship. verei quando chegar em casa e te mando um gist ou fiddle com um exemplo funcional ;)

Comment: Obrigado, Guilherme.